# Can slack channel link is not visible

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I am using a bot to do some api actions.
I am using slack `conversations.create` to create a new channel

```
{
  name: 'channel_name',
  is_private: false,
};
```

Then I post the channel name using `chat.postMessage`

```
{
  type: 'section',
  text: {
    type: 'mrkdwn',
    text: `INJECT <#${newChannelName}> HERE`,
  },
};
```

I want to see the link to the channel in the message, something like #channel_name , for user to be able to click on it and navigate to the channel itslef.
but i am getting "Private channel info"

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of formatting occurs when the marked channel, **though public** is **not accessible** to the user viewing this message.

There can be many reasons for this, one for example is that the channel belongs to one of the workspace on enterprise grid but the user is not member of that workspace.